# What are the sendmail options that can be used with the Linux mail command?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I'm trying to figure out how to get some of our servers to send email through our relay when I use the mail command. If I simply type

```
$ mail -s "Test" user@domain.com
```

mail attempts to send directly to the recipient which is not allowed on our network. All email must go through the SMTP server.

I tried using the -- option to pass sendmail options, but I don't know what the option is that I need to pass. I found in another forum that the -S option followed by smtp=smtp://ip.address is the appropriate choice, but that throws an error stating that the -S option doesn't exist.

```
$ mail -s "Test" user@domain -- -S smtp=smtp://ip.address
```

Looking at the man page for either mail or sendmail has not clued me into which option I need to use. I did see in the sendmail manpage that there is the -O option which uses the option=value format. I tried that instead of the -S listed above. Still no dice. The manpage even says the -O option is ignored.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

`sendmail` is the command to send mail from your local MTA/mailserver, which may or may not be THE server known as Sendmail.  Check and see what mailserver you have running.  While there's a subset of "compatible" options that every mailserver provides in its `sendmail` executable, each of them will provide other options for advanced usage, and you'd have to see if your mailserver's version has an option to set a server on an email-by-email basis.

Your best bet, no matter what server you have installed, is to configure the mailserver to use the appropriate SMTP server as a "smarthost" so that your outbound mail always uses it.